# JQuery: how to find element that lies after current element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Suppose, we have 2 checkboxes and 2 divs that follow the checkboxes:

[image]

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" checked="" />
</div>
<div class="border"></div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" checked="" />
</div>
<div class="border"></div>
```

My goal is to toggle the color of the appropriate "border" div, lying below the checkbox. The problem is, I don't know how to get the appropriate div. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(
    function  ()
    {
        var div = $(this).find('div');//<-- ?

        if ($(this).checked)
        {
            div.css("border", "solid 2px blue");
        }
        else
        {
            div.css("border", "solid 2px black");
        }
    });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gv3pqo2z/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `.find()` method will select any descendant elements.

Since the `input` element is self-closed and doesn't contain any descendant elements, nothing is selected with `$(this).find('div')`.

You could select the parent `div` element, and then the immediately following element:

```
$(this).parent().next();
```

The above will select the immediate parent element. It may be safer using the `.closest()` method in order to select the ancestor `.wrapper` element (just in case nesting varies):

```
$(this).closest('.wrapper').next();
```

In addition, jQuery objects don't have a `checked` property, you should retrieve the `checked` property of the DOM element, therefore `$(this).checked` should be `this.checked` or you could simply use the `.prop()` method to retrieve the `checked` property from the DOM element in the jQuery object by using: `$(this).prop('checked')`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/eqdy7eog/)

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  var div = $(this).closest('.wrapper').next();

  if (this.checked) {
    div.css("border", "solid 2px blue");
  } else {
    div.css("border", "solid 2px black");
  }
});
```

---

As a side note, I'd suggest simply toggling a class on the corresponding element instead:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/c24xwg6p/)

```
.border.blue-border {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('.wrapper').next().toggleClass('blue-border')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to `var div = $(this).parent().next('.border');`

Comment: This `var div = $(this).closest('.wrapper').next();` will be more reliable I think

Answer (score 1):

You need to take `parent().next()` as was mentioned in some answers...

Also, checkbox status was not valuated correctly.

Try this solution:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(
    function  () {
        var div = $(this).parent().next();

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            div.css("border", "solid 2px blue");
        } else {
            div.css("border", "solid 2px black");
        }
    }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gv3pqo2z/3/